# CSS background gradiant animation not working

Tags: css, animation, gradient

This animation is not working. I cant figure out why. Can someone please help me with this?

```
body {

background: linear-gradient(227deg, #8d369b, #3aa9bb, #e145f2);
background-size: 600% 600%;

-webkit-animation: Test 36s ease infinite;
-moz-animation: AnimationName 36s ease infinite;
animation: AnimationName 36s ease infinite;

@-webkit-keyframes Test {
0%{background-position:0% 51%}
50%{background-position:100% 50%}
100%{background-position:0% 51%}
}
@-moz-keyframes Test {
0%{background-position:0% 51%}
50%{background-position:100% 50%}
100%{background-position:0% 51%}
}
@keyframes Test { 
0%{background-position:0% 51%}
50%{background-position:100% 50%}
100%{background-position:0% 51%}
}}
```

I want my background to be animated with gradient. What is wrong with the code above?

Comment: Background gradient can't be animated :)

Comment: But `background-position` can, @BojanPetkovski.

Comment: @Shaggy It surely can. I started answering the question, but got on another one. I saw you gave the same answer so +1 for you :)

Answer (score 1):

You are defining your keyframes within the rules for the `body` tag. You also have the wrong `animation-name` defined for `-moz-animation` and `animation`. Here's the fixed version of your CSS.

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(227deg, #8d369b, #3aa9bb, #e145f2);
  background-size: 600% 600%;
  -webkit-animation: Test 36s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: Test 36s ease infinite;
  animation: Test 36s ease infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes Test {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 51%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 51%
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes Test {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 51%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 51%
  }
}
@keyframes Test {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 51%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 51%
  }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. If this has answered your question to your satisfaction, you might consider accepting it :)